# Google App Engine logs a mess of New connection for ... and Client closed local connection on

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Checking out my logs on my App Engine. I get A LOT of

```
New connection for "<project_id>-central1:<project_name>"
Client closed local connection on /cloudsql/<project_id>-central1:<project_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Like happening multiple times a second and just floods my logs.

I was unable to find any information relating to this and maybe this is just a non-issue.

- Is there any way to prevent this? (excluding filtering)
- Is this inadvertently driving up the cost of operation of opening and closing?

I am using Django on the app engine.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/44) post where it's mentioned that setting -verbose=false will turn off the new/closed connection logs.

Answer (score 0):

I found information about the same error but it wasn't generating a lot of connections. Anyway it was related to the Cloud SQL proxy.

Have you followed [the instructions in this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres#setting_up_your_local_environment) to configure the PostgreSQL connection to App Engine? I am particularly interested in the ones from "Setting up your local environment".

I did not found any related field in [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas) or [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) pages but you can check the billing in the Google Cloud Console: `Billing -> Overview -> [PROJECT_ID]`.

Comment: I have already set up `cloud_sql_proxy`. Which the logs to look similar, however, days after the app engine already being deployed and `cloud_sql_proxy` not running I still see a mess of the same repeated logs.

Comment: In terms of billing, I am unsure how to determine if reconnecting isn't being costly(low at the moment but could be lower?). If anything I can't imagine constantly reconnecting being efficient long term for the db connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a django developer but I guess the root of this problem is that django opens a new connection to the database for every request by default.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/

> Persistent connections avoid the overhead of re-establishing a connection to the database in each request. They’re controlled by the CONN_MAX_AGE parameter which defines the maximum lifetime of a connection. It can be set independently for each database.
>
> The default value is 0, preserving the historical behavior of closing
> the database connection at the end of each request. To enable
> persistent connections, set CONN_MAX_AGE to a positive number of
> seconds. For unlimited persistent connections, set it to None.

You can try to increase the **CONN_MAX_AGE** or set it to None and the log messages should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `CONN_MAX_AGE` value to `None` can help, however this may expose your application to bot attacks like exposed me (see the picture below):

[image: Google Cloud Platform]

Looking for the IP's in abuseIPDB.com I've found a lot of reports of Brute Force/Web App Attack from it.

Maybe setting the variable value to a fixed number may keep your application safe and stop these logs.